White to move and mate in one
Beginner puzzle (suitable for people who are new to puzzle solving).

White to move and mate in one:


Attribution:  chess.com

White should play

 Qb3#

Why does this work?

 - White's queen is now attacking Black's king on b8 and is also preventing him from moving to b7.
 - White's light-square bishop on h1 is protecting the knight on a8, which is in turn attacking c7.
 - White's dark-square bishop on g1 is protecting the knight on a7, which is in turn attacking c8.
 - Thus, the king cannot move. None of Black's pieces can block, and while the bishop looks like it could take the queen, it is pinned by White's rook on a8.

Why is this White's only mate in 1?

 - White's king, pawn, light-squared knight, and light-squared bishop obviously cannot check the king.
 - White could check with the other knight by playing Nc6, but that would allow Black to either move their king to c8 or take White's knight on a8.
 - White could check with their dark-squared bishop by playing Bh2, but that would allow Black to take the knight on a7, or block with the queen by moving her to d6.
 - White could also check with the rook by taking the bishop (i.e. Rxg8) but Black could once again block with the queen on d8.
 - Finally, White's queen can only move along the a2-g8 diagonal because it is pinned by Black's bishop. Despite this, she is the only White piece with two possible checking moves: she could also take the bishop on g8, but Black could once again block with their queen; or she could move to b3, which as established earlier, is checkmate.


+1 Very thorough!

The trick here is to notice that

 Black’s bishop is pinned to its king in the back rank by the rook and the white queen is pinned by the bishop.

However all one has to do is move

 Queen to b3. The bishop can’t take it because it is unable to move. The black queen can’t block the mate. Blacks king is unable to escape by taking on a7 or a8 because they are guarded by the bishops and the c7 and c8 squares and blocked by the knights.

Why do the other checks not work

 Bh2 is met with Qd6.
 Qxg8 or Rxg8 is met with Qd8.
 Nc6 then Kc8.


Are there not at least five other moves? I am not sure whether your first observation is necessary for most of them.

I have updated my answer

It seams to me that the solution is the following:

 Knight in C6

then must be:

 Q in F4


Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!  Unfortunately the White queen can’t move to c7 because then the White king would be attacked by the Black bishop.  Try again.

Thanks a lot and Greetings! I have to answer again or is better that I edit my answer?

Editing the answer is fine. :) But Bh2 is not it either, the black queen can block on d6

Finally I found it? (and why am I downvoted?)

The black king can move to c8 to avoid check. The downvotes are likely because the answer is currently wrong.

@pvt-Tron I love that you're still working on this question, and that you're working on getting the formatting correct! Don't let the downvotes bother you (I agree that the reason is likely because the answer is currently wrong). When you do get to the answer, just be aware that because the correct answer has already been posted, votes probably won't change much.

@tmpearce the correct answer is already posted (I  haven't opened spoilers atm)?

@pvt-Tron Yes, the answer with the green checkmark has been accepted, as it is correct and provides a full explanation. You may want to check out the logic outlined in that answer at some point.
